# Implementing lexicographic comparison for std::tuple in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to implement lexicographic comparison for std::tuple. I know the standard provides this. I'm doing it as a TMP exercise. I can't see why the code below doesn't work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I know the code below assumes operands of the same type. I am happy making this as a simplifying assumption.

I've looked at the VC++ 2013 and GCC 4.7 implementations. They both use non-standard helper classes to get the tail  (i.e. all but the left-most element) from a tuple. I'd like to solve the problem with as little scaffolding as possible. Is it possible to do tuple comparison without something like get_tail?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

// Pseudo-recursion.

template<class tupleT,std::size_t N>
struct tuple_ops {
    static bool less(const tupleT& x,const tupleT& y) {
        return std::get<N-1>(x) < std::get<N-1>(y) ||
            ( !(std::get<N-1>(y) < std::get<N-1>(x)) &&
              tuple_ops<tupleT,N-1>::less(x,y) );
    }
};

// Base Case.

template<class tupleT>
struct tuple_ops<tupleT,1> {
    static bool less(const tupleT& x,const tupleT& y) {
        return std::get<0>(x) < std::get<0>(y);
    }
};

// Convenience wrapper.

template<class... T>
bool operator<(const std::tuple<T...>& x,const std::tuple<T...>& y) {
    return tuple_ops<decltype(x),sizeof...(T)>::less(x,y);
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    auto tup0 = make_tuple(3.14,string("foo"),2.71);
    auto tup1 = make_tuple(4.01,string("foo"),2.01);
    auto tup2 = make_tuple(1,string("bar"),5);
    auto tup3 = make_tuple(1,string("foo"),5);

    cout <<  (::operator<(tup0,tup1))  << ' '
         <<  (::operator<(tup2,tup3))  << ' '
         << !(::operator<(tup1,tup0)) << ' '
         << !(::operator<(tup3,tup2)) << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Output: 0 1 0 1

Correct output would be: 1 1 1 1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp

Comment: Write index sequence from C++14.  Recuse using it and `std::get`.

Comment: @ juanchopanzo "I know the standard provides this. I'm doing it as a TMP exercise."

@ Yakk - I want to do this in C++11. (I could have stated this more clearly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is that your comparisons are backwards. Your first call is:

```
return tuple_ops<decltype(x),sizeof...(T)>::less(x,y);
```

which will call `tuple_ops<Type, 3>::less()`, the first operation of which compares `std::get<2>(x)` and `std::get<2>(y)`. So you're comparing the *last* elements first.

You have to start at `0` and go up to `N`, so you'd have to rewrite your first-level call to be:

```
return tuple_ops<decltype(x),0,sizeof...(T)>::less(x,y);
```

with the terminating case now being:

```
template <typename Tuple, size_t N>
struct tuple_ops<Tuple, N, N> {
    static bool less(const Tuple&, const Tuple&) { return false; }
};
```

---

A simpler way to avoid specializations would be to use an index sequence (and borrowing from Yakk's [now-deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32235477/2069064) to add more functionality):

```
template <class X, class Y>
bool operator<(const X& x, const Y& y) {
    return is_less(x, y,
        std::make_index_sequence<std::min(std::tuple_size<X>{},
                                          std::tuple_size<Y>{})>{});
}
```

Have an overload for the empty case:

```
template <typename X, typename Y>
bool is_less(X const&, Y const&, std::index_sequence<> ) {
    return std::tuple_size<X>{} < std::tuple_size<Y>{};
}
```

and an overload for the recursive case:

```
template <typename X, typenmae Y, size_t I, size_t... Is>
bool is_less(X const& x, Y const& y, std::index_sequence<I, Is...> ) {
    if (std::get<I>(x) < std::get<I>(y)) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (std::get<I>(y) < std::get<I>(x)) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return is_less(x, y, std::index_sequence<Is...>{});
    }
}
```

Comment: Beat me by 23 seconds.  You can write a 2 argument `is_less` that can be reused for `std::array` and `std::pair` if you move the making of the index sequence into it with `tuple_size` to make the sequence (see [deleted answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32235477/1774667)).  Also, `<` should work on non-uniform (yet compatible) types, no?

Comment: @Yakk Excellent points as usual. Probably the sizes don't even have to be the same right?

Comment: Hmm, with lexographic, what happens with equality up to the end of the shorter one? The longer one is ... later?

Comment: @Yakk That's how it works for strings, so that's what I'm going with.

Comment: I'm just testing before I upvote... Why should the terminating case always return true?

Comment: @arh That was a bug. Should always return `false` since a strict weak ordering must be irreflexive.

Answer (score 0):

Working like a charm. Here's a version of the test program, incorporating Barry's tips.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

// Pseudo-recursion.

template<class tupleT,std::size_t J,std::size_t N>
struct tuple_ops {
    static bool less(const tupleT& x,const tupleT& y) {
        return std::get<J>(x) < std::get<J>(y) ||
            ( !(std::get<J>(y) < std::get<J>(x)) &&
                tuple_ops<tupleT,J+1,N>::less(x,y) );
    }
};

// Base Case.

template <typename Tuple, size_t N>
struct tuple_ops<Tuple,N,N> {
    static bool less(const Tuple&, const Tuple&) {return false;}
};

// Convenience wrapper.

template<class... T>
bool operator<(const std::tuple<T...>& x,const std::tuple<T...>& y) {
    return tuple_ops<decltype(x),0,sizeof...(T)>::less(x,y);
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    auto tup0 = make_tuple(3.14,string("foo"),2.71);
    auto tup1 = make_tuple(4.01,string("foo"),2.01);
    auto tup2 = make_tuple(1,string("bar"),5);
    auto tup3 = make_tuple(1,string("foo"),5);

    cout <<  (::operator<(tup0,tup1)) << ' '
         <<  (::operator<(tup2,tup3)) << ' '
         << !(::operator<(tup1,tup0)) << ' '
         << !(::operator<(tup3,tup2)) << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks again.